# Justification for the MCTS backpropagation rule?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, monte-carlo-tree-search

In Monte Carlo Tree Search, we back-propagate the results of a simulation with reward $R$ to a parent node N like this
$$
V_N \leftarrow \frac{\text{visits}(N)\cdot V_N + R}{\text{visits}(N)+1}
$$
and $V_N$ is our first term in a selector like UCT.

I was looking at alternative MCTS selectors and realised this update rule is not so straightforward as I thought. With it, what we end up with is (for non leaf nodes)

$$
V_N = \sum_{N' \in \text{Children}(N)} \frac{V(N')\cdot\text{visits}(N')}{\text{visits}(N)}
$$

So $V_N$ seems to be the expectation of reward from $N$'s state, if the probability of us ending up at a child node is proportional to the number of times we visited it during tree expansion.

This is completely true if for instance, in the future we acted based on MCTS and did a random number of iterations $\leq \text{visits}(N)$ with $N$ as a root. With a fixed number of iterations though, we would always being doing at least $\geq \text{visits}(N)$ iterations. This implies to me that the child with the most visits (in the present) is overwhelmingly more likely to end up as the actual selected action, than is suggested by our $V_N$ formula.

Sorry if that last part wasn't clear. My point is that the $V_N$ estimate seems "off-policy". So it assumes we're going to act in a non-MCTS way. This is somewhat at odds with the case in MCTS where all children are leaves, and so their values are the actual simulation reward expectations.

Since final move selection is based on visit counts and not Q value, this probably doesn't affect the correctness of MCTS much. I wanted to ask if anyone knows if there is a better description of what $V(N)$ actually is, or if there is a good mathematical justification I am not seeing?